# Merge data frame with conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, merge, conditional-statements, apply

below are my data frames.

```
df1<-data.frame(month=c("march", "april"), apple=c(1,NA), peach=c(10,NA))
df2<-data.frame(month=c("march", "april"), apple=c(5,3), peach=c(NA,NA))
```

I want R to do the following:

- If cell values are present in both data frames – (cell value from df1)-(cell value from df2)
- If cell value from df1 is missing but cell value from df2 is present – write "first"
- If cell value from df2 is missing but cell value from df1 is present – write "second"
- If both are missing – write "both"

like this:

[image]

I tried `df1-df2` but the places where either data frames had NA were filled with NA.
Then I tried using apply function but couldn't really figure out how to do it...

Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Mixing characters and numbers in the same variable very rarely makes sense. I feel like you are describing your attempt at solving a problem  rather than the problem itself. see [XY Problem trap](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shree's comment is absolutely true: do not expect the `-4` value to be a number when you get the frame returned (it will actually be `"-4"`. I'm going to assume that something else is needing to happen here, so here's a solution to what you think you need :-)

```
func <- function(a,b) {
  naa <- is.na(a)
  nab <- is.na(b)
  ifelse(naa,
         ifelse(nab, "both", "first"),
         ifelse(nab, "second", a-b))
}
mapply(func, df1[2:3], df2[2:3], SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
# $apple
# [1] "-4"    "first"
# $peach
# [1] "second" "both"
```

I'm not always happy with nested `ifelse`, but this does not go extreme. This might be a better opportunity for `dplyr::case_when`, perhaps an exercise for later.

This can be applied back to a frame directly, such as:

```
df0 <- df1
df0[2:3] <- mapply(func, df1[2:3], df2[2:3], SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
df0
#   month apple  peach
# 1 march    -4 second
# 2 april first   both
```

But (again) as @Shree stated earlier, you won't have numbers in there:

```
str(df0)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ month: Factor w/ 2 levels "april","march": 2 1
#  $ apple: chr  "-4" "first"
#  $ peach: chr  "second" "both"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this is what you are looking for

````
```{r}
df1<-data.frame(month=c("march", "april"), apple=c(1,NA), peach=c(10,NA))
df2<-data.frame(month=c("march", "april"), apple=c(5,3), peach=c(NA,NA))

myconditions <- function(a, b) {
  if (is.na(a)) {
    if (is.na(b)) {
      "both"
    } else {
      "first"
    }
  } else {
    if(is.na(b)) {
      "second"
    } else {
      a - b
    }
  }
}

df1$apple[match(df2$month,df1$month)] <- mapply(myconditions,df1$apple,df2$apple)
df1$peach[match(df2$month,df1$month)] <- mapply(myconditions,df1$peach,df2$peach)

```
````

The resulting matrix will be in df1.

We start with your logic defined in the user defined function and then apply it to the vectors that you want to perform the operation on, so you were on the right track with apply.

As mentioned by others, you are mixing strings and integers so the data types of your columns are character vectors which may not be your goal here.